# Disable top/bottom hotspots on windows apps for paging

Tags: windows-8

I noticed when using reading apps like "News" and "Kindle" on Windows 8.1, when I move my mouse to the bottom of the screen, it scrolls down/right, and when I move the mouse to the top of the screen, it moves up/left.

This is really annoying me, and I can't find any option in the apps to turn the behavior off. Is there any setting in windows that can disable this behavior?

Update: this behavior only happens on my secondary monitor.

Update 2: Apparently no, it does happen on my primary monitor too, but only sometimes with some apps. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: What scrolls exactly?

Comment: The content scrolls

Comment: so, for example, it would go to the next/previous page of the article/book